# how to show repeated date value as null in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a SQL Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT DENSE_RANK() 
                OVER(ORDER BY bsContract.ContractNumber DESC) AS RANKS,
       ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER(PARTITION BY bsContract.ContractNumber ORDER BY bsContract.ContractNumber) 
         AS RowsNumber,
       dbo.bsContract.ContractNumber,
       Advertiser.OrganizationName AS Advertiser,
       JobName AS Campaign,
       bsContract.FromDate AS StartDate,
       Advertiser.OrganizationName AS Client,
       (ISNULL(bsContract.FirstName, '') + ' ' +
               bsContract.LastName) AS ClientRep,
       Advertiser.OrganizationName AS Vendor,
       (ISNULL(bsContract.FirstName, '') + ' ' +
               bsContract.LastName) AS 'VendorRep',
               DocumentType,
               FileType
   INTO #temp
   FROM dbo.bsContract     
  INNER JOIN Organization AS Advertiser
     ON Advertiser.OrganizationID = bsContract.OrganizationID
  WHERE FileType IS NULL
    AND bsContract.ContractNumber = 'CR6520'
    AND bsDocument.SellerID = 3632

   SELECT DISTINCT Ranks,
                   (CASE
                     WHEN RowsNumber = 1 THEN
                      ContractNumber
                     ELSE
                      ''
                   END) AS ContractNumber,
                   (CASE
                     WHEN RowsNumber = 1 THEN
                      Advertiser
                     ELSE
                      ''
                   END) AS Advertiser,
                   (CASE
                     WHEN RowsNumber = 1 THEN
                      Campaign
                     ELSE
                      ''
                   END) AS Campaign,
                   (CASE
                     WHEN RowsNumber = 1 THEN
                      StartDate
                     ELSE
                      (select convert(datetime, NULL))
                   END) AS StartDate,
                   Vendor,
                   VendorRep
           FROM #temp
          ORDER BY ContractNumber DESC
```

Everything is fine it gives the result. The first row gives the value
of `Contract Number, Advertiser Campaign, StartDate, Vendor and Vendor
Rep.` From 2nd row the value of `ContractNumber, Advertiser, Campaign,
StartDate` is same so it is shown as Blank. But the first row of the
result is displayed twice due to the Different `StartDate`. Refer attached screenshot:

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Request to you provide sample data and tables structure to get better result

Comment: try to use `group by` to avoid getting repetitive data.

Comment: Also put the output result set you are expecting.

Comment: Which of 2 must be excluded?

Comment: Row Number 5 should be excluded since Row number 1 and Row number 5 are same. It is shown twice because of different StartDate Value.

Comment: It will involve using group by and max() rather than distinct.

Comment: Great!!!! Using Group By Works!!